# Forcing at most once inclusion in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on an embedded system, written in ANSI C. For what its worth, it's a Pic32MX/MZ (we have systems on both), though it shouldn't be relevant. I also cannot make use of C++ or Rust.

I have written code to control a peripheral. I want to allow only 1 other file to reference this peripheral.

So imagine I have:

`perihperal1.h`
`peripheral1.c`
`my_file1.c` `myfile2.c`

Is there any way to ensure only 1 of `my_file1.c` or `myfile2.c` can have `#include perihperal1.h`?

I cannot find a way to force it in code, and would prefer forcing it, instead of relying just on good discipline.

Edit:

The purpose of this is some that I can separate the hardware initialization code from the business logic that may interact with said peripheral.

I want to avoid setting up a UART, and including it somewhere, and then having it also included elsewhere. It can be done with proper discipline, but in a large team errors do often occur.

Comment: No, there is no such thing. If you don't need it don't include it. OTOH including something you don't need doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: As you compile different C files independently there is no way to prevent inclusion of a header. The content of the other C files is unknown during compilation.

Comment: If you really need to do what you have said in the question, then I think it means that you are doing something seriously wrong!  The whole point of headers is that they are common.  Whatever it is in the header that needs to only happen once almost certainly doesn't belong in a header.  If you edit the question to show what the original problem was that made you think you wanted this as a solution then people might be able to suggest a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: If you include a header file only from one other file, doesn't that mean it shouldn't be in a separate file?

Comment: Sounds like the actual problem is that you didn't use header guards or maybe defined variables in a header.

Comment: Thought as much... Wishful thinking on my part, I hadn't been able to find anything before posting.
Including something You don't need doesn't cause harm, but I want to avoid having two files using the peripheral. 
This specific case is a UART, and I want to ensure that the peripheral is only ever called from one other file. This should make it easier to debug, and also prevent the code becoming too messy.
It will just have to come down to good discipline then.

Comment: @FlippievanDyk that brings us back to my preceeding comment. You don't want to be able to use stuff from `header.h` just don't include it; then as soon as you try to use something from `header.h` you'll get a compilation error. But maybe I misunderstood your question and you should clarify.

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, I think you understood it originally. The point is I want to stop anyone coming around to the code later and accessing the peripheral from another file. It almost inevitably lead to debugging nightmares.

Comment: @Cheatah Normally I would agree, but the point here is separating business logic from the peripherals that actually do the work. 
I get a data stream in from the UART, into a circular buffer, and I want to pass it to a function to consume it. I don't want  to deal with two files trying to consume the data, but again, without this, it will just come down to responsible coding.

Comment: I think you are trying to use wrong tool for the job. This sounds like human problem, not technical problem. Correct solution would be documentation, guidelines, training and code reviews.

Comment: Most embedded systems assume that the application is sensible and only call peripheral driver init functions from a single place in the code. That is not some special case, but everyday embedded systems programming. The only discipline necessary in this case would be "don't do really weird stuff". I added an answer though, if you feel that discipline isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is to document the UART code. Along the lines of "NOTE: this is a singleton implementation. It may only be called from a single code module in the project."

It is also possible to include run-time guards against such attempts as well. Suppose you have `uart_init` which must be executed first in order to use the driver. You can then implement it as:

```
uart_result_t uart_init (/* params */)
{
  static bool initialized=false;
  if(initialized)
  {
    return UART_ERR_MULTIPLE_CALLS; // some error code
  }
  initialized=true;
  ...
}
```

This adds a minimum of run-time overhead and attempting to do multiple calls will get spotted early on during development.

---

That is, unless you wish the code to handle multiple identical UART peripherals on the same MCU, then you need to implement it differently. For example as an opaque type that flags the specified UART peripheral as taken and returns an error like in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

If there is any legitimate reason for doing such, you could do something like this:

a.h:

```
int unique_include_a = 1;
```

a.c:

```
#include "a.h"

int a()
{
  return 123;
}

int main()
{
  a();
  return 0;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include "a.h"

int b()
{
  return 456;
}
```

Compile and link:

```
gcc a.c b.c
```

The linker should issue an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmC6JPZ.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `unique_include_a'; /tmp/ccjvwQrZ.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: So basically just removing the guard rails. Tested and it does work. I must admit I don't like it, though I see why it works, I might just play with the guard rails, I think that is definitely an option to solving my problem, but I am a starting to think this may be more a rabbit hole than it's worth.